# Map text value to numbers

Tags: excel, vba, cluster-analysis

I have an excel with a list of countries that I would like to map to IDs in order to analyze the data to create clusters.

The data I have looks like this:

[image]

and I would like to map for example Denmark with 1, Finland with 2, etc.

[image]

I was thinking on using two other columns as reference for the mapping process:

[image]

Is there a more automatic way than find and replace?

thanks!

Comment: do a VLOOKUP on your mapping table.

Comment: See [VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).